# asp.net mvc System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException on update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm using asp.net mvc with linq to sql repositories and the following code is throwing an   mvc System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException exception on this._table.Attach(entity)

My code is something like that:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        return View(_controllerRepository.GetById(id));
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(Directivo entity)
    {
        try
        {
         _repository.Save(entity, this.UserName)

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View(ex);
        }
    }
```

And in the repository:

```
    public virtual void Save(T entity, string userName)
    {
        if (0 == entity.Id)
        { 
            entity.UsuarioIntroduccion = userName;
            entity.FechaIntroduccion = DateTime.Now;
            entity.UsuarioModificacion = null;
            entity.FechaModificacion = null;

            this._table.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            entity.UsuarioModificacion = userName;
            entity.FechaModificacion = DateTime.Now;

            this._table.Attach(entity);
            this._table.Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, entity);
        }
        try
        {
            this._dataContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw new DataContextException(ex);
        }

    }
```

Note that the Id isn't 0.

Its really weird because it happens only with this class, i have a couple more that are working well.

The table is that:

```
CREATE TABLE [Directivo](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [Apellidos] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [FechaNacimiento] [datetime] NULL,
    [CargoDirectivoId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PathImagen] [varchar](250) NULL,
    FechaIntroduccion datetime not null,
    UsuarioIntroduccion varchar(45) not null,
    FechaModificacion datetime,
    UsuarioModificacion varchar(45),
    PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (CargoDirectivoId)
        REFERENCES CargoDirectivo(Id)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION 
)
```

And the class is the autogenerated by linq and a partial class that makes it inherit an interface, and sets the buddy class for metadata to use xVal

Do you have any clues about what could be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the 'Directivo' class look like?

Comment: I updated my question with this information, thanks!

Comment: Sorry but no... if it's only happening with that one class I would suggest comparing it to other Linq2SQL classes to see what the difference is. I'd also follow two a different Linq2SQL entity through the debugger to see what differences there are at different stages. Other than that I can't really help sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in `this._table.Attach(entity);` move this line up before setting the new values as follows

```
public virtual void Save(T entity, string userName)
{
    if (0 == entity.Id)
    { 
        entity.UsuarioIntroduccion = userName;
        entity.FechaIntroduccion = DateTime.Now;
        entity.UsuarioModificacion = null;
        entity.FechaModificacion = null;

        this._table.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
    }
    else
    {
        this._table.Attach(entity);

        entity.UsuarioModificacion = userName;
        entity.FechaModificacion = DateTime.Now;

        this._table.Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, entity);
    }
    try
    {
        this._dataContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        throw new DataContextException(ex);
    }

}
```

and this may help you http://www.richardbushnell.net/2008/02/18/how-to-update-data-with-linq-to-sql/